# How should I modify to only count the frequency of paired of value without considering the location/names of column?

Tags: r

I want to count the frequency of paired value in two column, but I want to ignore the paired location. Such as the example below, the general aggregate or table function would reports
three paired values (-0.25, 0.9), (0.9, -0.25) and (-0.77,2.9), but what I want to get is only two pairs which are (-0.25, 0.9) and (-0.77,2.9). How should I modify to only count the frequency of paired of value without considering the column location/names?

```
data <- data.frame(col1=c(-.25, 0.9, -.25, -.77, -.25),
                   col2=c(0.9, -.25, 0.9, 2.9, 0.9))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Given data `data <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"), col2 = c("c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c"))`, we can try

```
aggregate(
  freq ~ .,
  transform(
    data,
    col1 = pmin(col1, col2),
    col2 = pmax(col1, col2),
    freq = 1
  ),
  sum
)
```

which gives

```
  col1 col2 freq
1    a    a    1
2    a    c    3
3    c    c    2
```

---

Try this

```
> data[!duplicated(cbind(do.call(pmax, data), do.call(pmin, data))), ]
   col1 col2
1 -0.25  0.9
4 -0.77  2.9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I never used do. call function. So if I have column here is not numerical nut categorical. Would the same code works? Also I find the frequency for paired- value is reversed. Why is this happen?

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Thanks for your answer, but I never used do. call function. So if I have column here is not numerical nut categorical. Would the same code works? Also I find the frequency for paired- value is reversed. Why is this happen?

Comment: @huijia sorry that I forgot to reply you. You can type `?do.call` to read its use manual with more details. Here, in your example, `do.call(pmin,list(a,b)` is equivalent to `pmin(a,b)`. If you have categorical columns, I am not sure if the code works well in the same way. Perhaps you can share your data using `dput()` and then let's try if it could work.

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Thank for your reply.  Suppose I have the data below      data <- data.frame(col1=c("a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"), col2=c("c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c"))  ~~~                                                                                                                     
 the a-c pair appears 3 time and a-a pair appear 1 time and c-c pair appears two times. I tried your code which also collect the unique pair but the frequency is not.

Comment: @huijia Okay, I got your point now. You can see my update

Comment: Thanks!@ThomaslsCoding

Answer (score 1):

One solution. First, we paste together the two columns:

```
paste(data$col1, data$col2)
[1] "-0.25 0.9" "0.9 -0.25" "-0.25 0.9" "-0.77 2.9" "-0.25 0.9"
```

Then split them into a list:

```
str_split(paste(data$col1, data$col2), " ")
[[1]]
[1] "-0.25" "0.9"  

[[2]]
[1] "0.9"   "-0.25"

[[3]]
[1] "-0.25" "0.9"  

[[4]]
[1] "-0.77" "2.9"  

[[5]]
[1] "-0.25" "0.9"
```

Create a custom function to sort and paste the values back together and `sapply` to the list:

```
count_function = function(x) {
    x = sort(x)
    paste(x, collapse=", ")
}
sapply(str_split(paste(data$col1, data$col2), " "), count_function)
[1] "-0.25, 0.9" "-0.25, 0.9" "-0.25, 0.9" "-0.77, 2.9" "-0.25, 0.9"
```

Then take the unique values of this vector:

```
> table(sapply(str_split(paste(data$col1, data$col2), " "), count_function))

-0.25, 0.9 -0.77, 2.9 
         4          1
```

Comment: Thanks but does this report the frequency of each pair?

Comment: @huijia you can just wrap the output in ``table()`` - see edit.

Comment: Thanks but the frequency shown is 1 for each pair, however -0.25,0.9 should shows 3 for frequency.@user438383

Comment: Please see edit. It should have frequency of 4 and 1, since there are 5 rows in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(col1=c(-.25, 0.9, -.25, -.77, -.25),
                   col2=c(0.9, -.25, 0.9, 2.9, 0.9))
data %>%
  # Create min, max (col1, col2 respectively); uses temporary column to
  # not clobber the values in col2.
  mutate(
    col2.tmp = pmax(col1, col2),
    col1 = pmin(col1, col2),
    col2 = col2.tmp) %>%
  # Remopve temporary column.
  select(-col2.tmp) %>%
  # Determine frequency of pair.
  count(col1, col2, name = "frequency") %>%
  arrange(desc(col1))

#    col1 col2 frequency
# 1 -0.25  0.9         4
# 2 -0.77  2.9         1
```